# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql

I have the following script which has stopped working due the error in the title. Could someone please provide some assistance?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
         Locs.lCustomerGroupPK, Locs.lCustomerID, Locs.Customer_Group_Name, Locs.Customer_Name, Locs.Location_Name, TY.ThisYearsSales,
        (SELECT ThisYearsSales
           FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year
          WHERE (lLocationID = Locs.lLocationID2 OR lLocationID = Locs.llocationid)
            AND (Current_Read_Date = TY.Current_Read_Date - 364) AND (ThisYearsSales <= 400)
         ) AS LastYearsSales, 
         TY.Current_Read_Date - 1 AS Current_Read_Date INTO #tmplocationlflsales
  FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year AS TY 
        INNER JOIN dbo.vw_locations_Like_For_Like_Previous AS Locs 
                ON TY.lLocationID = Locs.llocationid OR TY.lLocationID = Locs.lLocationID2
 WHERE (TY.ThisYearsSales <= 400)
    AND (TY.Current_Read_Date = @RecordDate)
    AND TY.ThisYearsSales IS NOT NULL
    AND (SELECT ThisYearsSales
           FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year
          WHERE (lLocationID = Locs.lLocationID2 OR lLocationID = Locs.llocationid) 
            AND (Current_Read_Date = TY.Current_Read_Date - 364) 
            AND (ThisYearsSales <= 400)
         ) IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY Locs.Customer_Group_Name, Locs.Customer_Name, Locs.Location_Name, Current_Read_Date
```

Comment: Please format your SQL query appropriately next time

Comment: First time user. How do i format properly?

Comment: Select the block and hit <CNTL>K

Comment: Like it says, one of your subqueries `(SELECT ...` is returning more than one row which is illegal; identify which one by running it in isolation if necessary & add conditions that limit the results to the one specific row you need/expect

Comment: Thanks Dor Cohen for editing :-). Alex, I'm having trouble finding which statement is causing the issue.

Comment: Suggest moving the repeated subquery block `SELECT ThisYearsSales` into a CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would seem to be the subquery in the SELECT:

```
        SELECT ThisYearsSales
        FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year
        WHERE (lLocationID = Locs.lLocationID2 OR 
                lLocationID = Locs.llocationid) 
            AND (Current_Read_Date = TY.Current_Read_Date - 364) 
            AND (ThisYearsSales <= 400)
```

This is returning too many rows.  Perhaps you want to change it to:

```
        SELECT sum(ThisYearsSales)
        FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year
        WHERE (lLocationID = Locs.lLocationID2 OR 
                lLocationID = Locs.llocationid) 
            AND (Current_Read_Date = TY.Current_Read_Date - 364) 
            AND (ThisYearsSales <= 400)
```

Since you use the same subquery twice, you should really put it in the FROM clause.

Comment: This seems to have worked. I am no longer receiving the error and my entire query is running. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you have this subquery in your script

```
SELECT ThisYearsSales
FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year
WHERE (lLocationID = Locs.lLocationID2 OR lLocationID = Locs.llocationid) 
 AND (Current_Read_Date = TY.Current_Read_Date - 364) 
 AND (ThisYearsSales <= 400)
```

If this returns a single value (one column in one record), than it will be included in your result, however, if this returns more than one row, you'll get the error you're getting.

Take a look at the data in the Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year view to see if there are duplicates per lLocationID / Current_Read_Date, since those are the fields you are filtering by. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT count(*), lLocationID, Current_Read_Date 
FROM dbo.Vw_Level_3_Sales_This_Year
GROUP BY lLocationID, Current_Read_Date 
HAVING count(*)>1
```

Any rows returned by this query should indicate where the problem is.

Comment: Hi I ran the query you provided and it returned zero rows.

Comment: There is some sort of duplicate in there. Try to run the original script without the subquery to verify that's where the error is, or try to run my query without the Current_Read_Date grouping. If the view is small enough try also to inspect it visually, you might notice the offending values.

Comment: I ran the query without the Current_Read_Date grouping and it returned 2518 rows.